# If $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$ then $\lim_{h \to 0} \int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

A sequence of **mollifiers** $(\rho_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is any sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$$
\rho_n \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d), \quad \operatorname{supp} \rho_n \subset \overline{B(0,1 / n)}, \quad \int \rho_n=1, \quad \rho_n \geq 0 \text { on } \mathbb{R}^d.
$$

Then we have a result from Brezis's [Functional Analysis](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7.pdf?pdf=button), i.e.,

> **Theorem 4.22.** Assume $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Then $(f*\rho_n) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Now I would like to prove below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** If $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$, then
> $$
> \lim_{h \to 0} \int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x = 0.
> $$

- Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?
- Is there a shorter approach without using mollifiers?

---

**Proof** Let $(\rho_n)$ be a sequence of mollifiers. We have
$$
\begin{align}
&\int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x \\
\le &\int |f(x+h)- (f * \rho_n) (x+h)| d x + \int |(f * \rho_n) (x+h) - f(x)| d x \\
= &\int |f(x)- (f * \rho_n) (x)| d x + \int |(f * \rho_n) (x+h) - f(x)| d x.
\end{align}
$$

Let $K := \operatorname{supp} \rho_n$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
&|(f * \rho_n) (x+h)| \\
\le{} &\int_K |f(x+h-y)| \rho_n (y) d y \\
\le{} &\|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_K |f(x+h-y)| d y \quad \text{by Hölder's inequality} \\
\le{} &\|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_K |f(x+y)| d y \quad \text{by translation-invariance of } \lambda.
\end{align}
$$

We define $g:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x) := \|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_K |f(x+y)| d y$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\|g\|_{L^1} &= \|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \int_K |f(x+y)| d y dx \\
&= \|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_K  \int_{\mathbb R^d}  |f(x+y)| d x dy \quad \text{by Tonelli's theorem}\\
&= \|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \int_K  \|f\|_{L^1} dy \\
&= \lambda(K) \|\rho_n\|_{L^\infty} \|f\|_{L^1} <\infty.
\end{align}
$$

Hence $g \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$. Notice that $f * \rho_n$ is smooth, so
$$
(f * \rho_n) (x+h) - f(x) \xrightarrow[]{h \to 0} (f * \rho_n) (x) - f(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
$$

On the other hand
$$
|(f * \rho_n) (x+h) - f(x)| \le |g(x)| + |f(x)|.
$$

Clearly, $g+f \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$. By dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \int |(f * \rho_n) (x+h) - f(x)| d x = \int |(f * \rho_n) (x) - f(x)| d x.
$$

Hence
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x \le 2\int |(f * \rho_n) (x) - f(x)| d x.
$$

The claim then follows by **Theorem 4.22.** and by taking the limit $n \to \infty$.

---

**Update** I have found a simpler approach. Still we need a result from Brezis's [Functional Analysis](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7.pdf?pdf=button), i.e.,

> **Corollary 4.23.** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Then $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p<\infty$.

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. By **Corollary 4.23.**, there is $g \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\|f-g\|_{L^1} < \varepsilon$. By dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \int |g(x+h)-g(x)| d x = 0.
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align}
& \int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x \\
\le{} & \int |f(x+h)-g(x+h)| d x + \int |g(x+h)-g(x)| d x + \int |g(x)-f(x)| d x \\
={} & 2 \|f-g\|_{L^1} + \int |g(x+h)-g(x)| d x \quad \text{by translation-invariance of } \lambda.
\end{align}
$$

Hence
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \int |f(x+h)-f(x)| d x \le 2 \varepsilon.
$$

The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$.

Comment: It's fine. There are already several posting that cover this in MSE.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you so much for your verification!